# Does the link tag order make a difference in html?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use Google Fonts, is there any difference between the 1st case and the 2nd case? For example, whether the font defined in the styles.css file is rendered in the browser late in the second case.

```html
<!-- 1st case -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="google font url">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
```

```html
<!-- 2nd case -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="google font url">
```

Comment: yes, because The css is cascade...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna use the font you are getting from Google in `styles.css` you would wanna take the first approche, this one:

```html
<!-- 1st case -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="google font url">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
```

Otherwise, you couldn't, cause CSS is getting interpreted top to bottom. If you wanna see a difference use for example this font in this order:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shizuru&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
```

And in your `styles.css`, define the following:

```
 *{
   font:inherit;
 }
 html{
  font-family: 'Shizuru', cursive;
 }
```

Take a look at the page, and then change the order like so and see the difference:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shizuru&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, CSS files are loaded in the order that they appear in the page.
Thus, if your second link somehow conflicts with the first one the later will apply.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it make a difference.

There is a simple rule the later defined overwrite earlier defined styles.

In 1st case you have some control over the final page style because you can modify attributes defined from 3rd party styles.